# Prolog - Issue using math operators

Tags: prolog

I have a set of rules that consist of;

family(Mother,Father,Children), where children is a list (e.g. [ag,bg]) and person/6. The date is person in set out as Day,Month,Year.

I want to say that if two children who are not born in the same or consecutive days must be a year apart.
I've been at this for hours and just cannot seem to get anywhere, below is my code, which I personally cannot see why it would not work.
Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

```
bad_children() :-
      family(_,_,Q),
      member(J,Q),
      member(T,Q),
      person(J,_,_,_,date(E,M,Y),place(_,_)),
      person(T,_,_,_,date(F,M,K),place(_,_)),
      ( E \= F ; E \= (F+1) ; E \= (F-1) ),
      (Y-K) < 1
   ;  (K-Y) < 1,
      write(J),
      write(' and '),
      write(T),
      write(' are born to close together.').
```

Answer (score 1):

the main mistake is about operator (\=)/2. It does mean `don't unify`, and it doesn't perform arithmetic evaluation.

Also, you should bracket the disjunction `(Y-K) < 1 ; (K-Y) < 1`.

So, the (untested) code could be

```
bad_children :-
 family(_,_,Q),
 member(person(J,_,_,_,date(E,M,Y),_),Q), % You're not interested in place/2
 member(person(T,_,_,_,date(F,M,K),_),Q),
 J \= T, % Regardless the date, you should check the identity. Here \= is fine
 (E =\= F; E =\= F+1; E =\= F-1),
 (Y-K < 1 ; K-Y < 1),
 format('~w and ~w are born to close together.', [J, T]).
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, the correct outputs are printing but it is printing the answer 3 times, do you have any idea why this would happen?

Comment: most likely because there are multiple matches. Maybe you can change the condition I've posted about identity to `J @< T`. I was interested in showing you where `\=` could be appropriately used, but my choice was a bit unfortunate.

Comment: I forgot to use \= between J and T, I realized I should have used it after I saw the trace results. I'm sorry to ask but I've seen the months should come into as well as it is seeing if they are less then a year apart so just evaluating the year doesn't work. Would you have any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: I think you should do your computing. Better to rite a separate predicate that evaluates true when you pass to it date/3 arguments. Time/date handling in SWI-Prolog (as any other language I know of) can be really complicated, not worth for this use case.